# AJAX Jquery PHP Form Validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I would like to create a comment form based on the jquery validation plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). How do I configure the form to submit using AJAX? Right now I cant get the form to submit without going to the next page (process.php). I want it to stay on the form page.

The code is pretty much straight from jquery currently.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#commentForm").submit(function () {
            if ($("#commentForm").validate()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'process.php',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (returnedData) {
                        $('#commentForm').append(returnedData);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>


<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="POST" action="process.php">
<label for="cname">Name</label>
<em>*</em><input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />

<label for="cemail">E-Mail</label>
<em>*</em><input id="cemail" name="email" size="25"  class="required email" />

<label for="curl">URL</label>
<em>  </em><input id="curl" name="url" size="25"  class="url" value="" />
<label for="ccomment">Your comment</label>
<em>*</em><textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" cols="22"  class="required"></textarea>

<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

And the php is pretty standard too:

```
<?php

$to      = 'sdfsadfssfasd@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

print "Form submitted successfully: <br>Your name is <b>".$_POST['cname']."</b> and your email is <b>".$_POST['email']."</b><br>";
?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#commentForm").submit(function(){
        if($("#commentForm").validate()){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'process.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(returnedData){
                    alert(returnedData);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I insert the php response "Form submitted successfully" inside the form? Printing this via php results in a browser popup

Comment: Should I create a php variable to pass to the form then create an "if" statement to include the final confirmation? Or is there an easier way via jquery / ajax?

Comment: I will start a new question for this issue. Thanks for answering my question

Comment: Found the solution to both issues. My first post now has the complete correct code. Question solved. Thanks.